# PHP mail() claiming sent but not received

Tags: php, email

I've created a PHP form to send an email and when testing it says sent but is never received.

I've checked that each string is fetched correctly

This is the script:

```
<?PHP

$name = $_POST["name"];
$theyare = $_POST["whatareyou"];
$usermail = $_POST["email"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];

$to = "Myemail@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Website contact";

$message = "A new comment was given by $name 
    \nThey Are: $theyare 
    \n Comment: $comment 
    \n\n Email: $usermail";

$message = wordwrap($message,70);

if(mail($to,$subject,$message))
{
echo "sent to $to";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

I know this just got marked as repeat question but I select it as a differant one as its differant code and a differant server

Comment: Are you sending on local machine?

Comment: If you have access to the server logs, check the smtp mail logs. They're usually somewhere in /var/log

Comment: is this on a hosted server, or your own? is there an MTA installed on the server? is it configured? windows or linux? have you looked at the logs of the mail server?

Comment: Try using a library like PHPMailer, which can debug what the server is actually telling you

Comment: Im using 000webhost to host the site so its not on a local and its not comming back with any form of error that I can see its just not sending it

Comment: if it is being sent, then don't forget to check the spam box

Comment: I did check the spam of all the emails i tryed sending it to, I even tryed creating a fresh mail address for it, with no luck